# I hate the analog time picker, can I force apps to use something else?

Tags: clock, user-interface, date-and-time

## I really dislike this:

[image: android analog time picker]

---

## I would love to be able to force all of my apps to use this:

[image: android digital time picker]

I realize that everyone has their own opinions about good vs bad UX.  I don't want to start fights, **I am just wondering if there is a way to force my phone to always use the digital time picker rather than the analog clock face.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Android OS has [a built-in date and picker](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/components/pickers) that can be used in any app, but app developers can create and use their own picker.**

The time picker that is shown in the question was *Google apps' own customization*. Thus, other apps will normally show like this instead:

[image: pickers from Android Developers]

*Android doesn't have a setting for date-time picker customization*, thus it is not possible to change it, other than perhaps using a custom ROM that implements a built-in date-time picker similar to Google's.

(As a reference, there is a [3rd-party library](https://github.com/derekbrameyer/android-betterpickers/) that implements the digital time picker from the previous Google Calendar, but it's only useful for developers).

Comment: If that's the case, nuts.

Comment: Well, don't count on me on this thing. This is only from app developer point-of-view, not from ROM developer. Perhaps there is a way if using custom ROM, but I don't have experience on that.